# wp_get_attachment_image_src() returns wrong url

Tags: media, attachments

wp_get_attachment_image_src() is returning a wrong image url. It returns the original url instead of the cropped one. Here some example code:

```
    $ptId = get_post_thumbnail_id( $productId );
    print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src( $ptId, 'thumbnail'));
    print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src( $ptId, 'medium'));
    print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src( $ptId, 'medium_large'));
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => //localhost:3000/.../wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Mineral-Lipstick-Crème-Brûlée-scaled-1.jpg [1] => 100 [2] => 150 [3] => ) 
Array ( [0] => //localhost:3000/.../wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Mineral-Lipstick-Crème-Brûlée-scaled-1.jpg [1] => 200 [2] => 300 [3] => ) 
Array ( [0] => //localhost:3000/.../wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Mineral-Lipstick-Crème-Brûlée-scaled-1.jpg [1] => 768 [2] => 1152 [3] => )
```

The image sizes do exist and you can see that the function 'kind of' detects them. I've also regenerated them (both with wp-cli & the regenerate thumbnails plugin) just to be on the sure side but alas.

I don't quite get it, I've been using this function for years and suddenly I'm not getting the desired results. Any idea as to what might be going wrong?